# How can I draw this graph with axis from tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, axis, node-connections

Good Evenning, i want draw this graph that has 2 graph, i use the tikzpicture package and axis.

A graph is a signal input(left), and anotar is signal output (below).

[image]
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines= middle, xlabel={$V[v]$}, ylabel={$I$}, xlabel style={above right},ylabel style={above left}, xmin= 0, xmax = 10, ymin=0, ymax = 0.001, y post scale = 1.5]
      \addplot[domain= 0:10, samples = 100, thick,green] {((-0.0001)*x)+0.001)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.1,0)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.19,0.000001)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.29,0.000001)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.36,0.000004)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.40,0.00001)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.40,0.00002)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.45,0.000025)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.46,0.000034)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.45,0.000045)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.48,0.000052)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.50,0.00015)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.50,0.00025)};
      \addplot[red, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.57,0.00034)};
      \addplot[blue, mark=*, only marks] coordinates{(0.60,0.00094)};
      \draw (axis cs: 0.1,0) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.19,0.000001) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.29,0.000001) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.36,0.000004) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.40,0.00001) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.40,0.00002) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.45,0.000025) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.46,0.000034) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.45,0.000045) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.48,0.000052) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.50,0.00015) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.50,0.00025) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.57,0.00034) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (axis cs: 0.60,0.00094) circle [radius=1];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: At least a cleaner picture!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You say that you use Ti*k*Z. Could you please post some code of what you tried so far then?

Comment: I'm sorry, but is just a line, for example: $y= -mx+b$, and the others are sin ir cos function.

Comment: A do it for me type of question is not welcome on this site. You need to show some code and describe what is causing you problems.

Comment: Here is the code.

Comment: So you want to demonstrate amplification, e.g. in electronics? // What‘s the purpose of the discrete data with the circles? // Not sure how the timelines are oriented in your sketch, for input, output and on the transfer characteristic. // What do you want to visualize?